# if __name__ == "__main__": equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, python

With python, I can use `if __name__ == "__main__":` for using the module both as a library and a program.

- Can I mimic this feature in C#?

I see a class in C# can have a 'static void Main()', but I'm not sure if every class can have a Main() without a problem.

### ADDED

/m:CLASS_NAME is a way to specify the class to run the Main().

Comment: How about a stub Console project? Python can get away with this because they don't need to know at build time if it's a library or an executable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put a `Main` method in as many classes as you like, although only one can be an entry point for an application. (For talks, I often have a main method in every class, and use a helper library to present all of those pseudo-entry-points when I run the project.)

Likewise you can definitely add a reference to a .exe assembly and treat it like a library. For example, you *could* make a unit testing assembly work like a class library in most cases, but also write a main method so that you could just run it to execute the tests without a GUI or whatever.

Comment: You're never gonna let me win one of these, are you? :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can compile a C# project as a program (executable) with a Main() method, and you'd still be able to use it as a library. No special syntax required.

You *could* add a Main() method to every class, but I doubt it's useful.

.NET applications usually have different structures than Python ones; trying to fit the same programming model is unlikely to get you good results.

Answer (score 1):

C# project files specify a startup object when multiple entry points are available.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) article for more info.